# Why does Sonatype Nexus respond with a 405 error to `npm login`?

Tags: npm, nexus

When I attempt to `npm login` into to our Nexus Repository Manager npm repository, I get a response saying:

```sh
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! Registry returned 405 for PUT on http://hostname/-/user/org.couchdb.user:ci

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-23T17_30_33_494Z-debug.log
```

When I run the command with `--verbose` I get another hint saying:

```sh
npm http 405 ← HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL (http://hostname/-/user/org.couchdb.user:ci)
```

Why is it not letting me log in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to supply the repository path in your registry URL.

Your registry URL is set to `http://hostname/`, which is only the base name of your NRM, which could hold multiple repositories with discrete permissions.

You need to provide the repository name like `http://hostname/repository/npmjs-proxy/`.